# Validation preventing refresh/restart - tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I've added validation to my tkinter entry widget to only allow numbers.I've added code which I thought would also allow an entry widget to be empty to enable my refresh and restart functions.

When the restart or refersh buttons are pressed I want both the entry widget and text area to be cleared.  Currently only the text area is clearing.  The numbers remain in the entry widget.  Suggested amendments to my code would be appreciated.

```
def __init__(self, parent, controller):
    tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
    self.controller = controller
    ...
    vcmd = (self.register(self.onValidate), '%S')
    self.weight_entry = tk.Entry(self, validate='key', vcmd = vcmd)
    self.weight_entry.pack(pady = 10)
    self.text = tk.Text(self)
    self.text.pack(pady = 10)
    self.text.config(state='disabled')
    Restart_button = tk.Button(self, text="Restart", command=self.restart)
    Refresh_button = tk.Button(self, text="Refresh", command=self.refresh)
    ...


# Code below adds validation to the Entry widget so only numbers can be entered
def onValidate(self,s):
    if (self.weight_entry ==""):"""Not sure if this is correct.  Taken from another answer on SO."""
        return True
    if s in ['0','1','2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']: 
        return True
    else:
        self.bell() # adds a sound effect to error
        self.text.delete(1.0, tk.END) # deletes the error message if valid entry provided
        return False

def restart(self):
    self.refresh()
    self.controller.show_frame("StartPage")

def refresh(self):
    self.weight_entry.delete(0,tk.END)
    self.text.config(state='normal')
    self.text.delete("1.0", "end")
    self.text.config(state='disabled')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you cannot delete the whole content of the entry is because in `onValidate` you expect `s` to be a single digit, but if your entry contains '123', when you call `delete(0, "end")`, then `s` = '123' so `onValidate` returns False.

To solve this, you can do:

```
def onValidate(self, s):
    if s.isdigit():  # no need to test if the entry is empty because the deleted text contains only digits
        return True
    else:
        self.bell() # adds a sound effect to error
        self.text.delete(1.0, tk.END) # deletes the error message if valid entry provided
        return False
```